# Freemarker iteration from Spring-bound list

Tags: spring-mvc, freemarker

I have a `List<String>` bound by a Spring `ModelAttribute`. How do I iterate over it in Freemarker?

I've tried:

```
<#list ${modelattribute.listField} as thing >
    <tr><td>${thing}</td></tr></#list>
</#list>
```

But Freemarker is not expecting the escape sequence

```
Encountered "{" at line 108, column 43 in things/search.html.
Was expecting one of: ...
```

How should I reference this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
<#list modelattribute.listField as thing >
    <tr><td>${thing}</td></tr></#list>
</#list>
```